# How can I code this Interesting Condition Join SQL

Tags: sql, join, conditional-statements

In a nutshell here is what I want to happen:

Complete the join, if the rows do not exist do the same join but using one different value to fill the null columns in each row.

Here is my join:

```
Left Join CMS_ECH.dbo.hsplit hsplit on hsplit.row_date = ANDREWSTABLE.SegStart_Date 
and hsplit.split=ANDREWSTABLE.dispsplit 
and hsplit.starttime = ANDREWSTABLE.Interval 
and hsplit.acd = ANDREWSTABLE.acd1
```

Where ACD1 is either 1 or 4.

For some rows there will be nulls.

If the result of the join returns a null row_date then... and here is where my knowledge fails me... so for the sake of no other words to describe it... rejoin the null rows in the table using a different value for acd1. If acd1 = 1 then use 4. If acd1 is 4 then use 1.

I am using MS SQL 2005

Answer (score 1):

This'll do it, it won't perform brilliantly as the CASE statement will interfere with index choice, however give it a go and hope for the best.

```
SELECT COALESCE(hsplit.requiredfield, hsplit2.requiredfield) AS requiredfield,
...
Left Join CMS_ECH.dbo.hsplit hsplit on hsplit.row_date = ANDREWSTABLE.SegStart_Date 
and hsplit.split=ANDREWSTABLE.dispsplit 
and hsplit.starttime = ANDREWSTABLE.Interval 
and hsplit.acd = ANDREWSTABLE.acd1
Left Join CMS_ECH.dbo.hsplit hsplit2 on hsplit2.row_date = ANDREWSTABLE.SegStart_Date 
and hsplit2.split=ANDREWSTABLE.dispsplit 
and hsplit2.starttime = ANDREWSTABLE.Interval 
and CASE WHEN hsplit2.acd = 1 THEN 4 WHEN hsplit2.acd = 4 THEN 1 WHEN ... END = ANDREWSTABLE.acd1
```

Answer (score 0):

Most (if not all) SQL dialects have an [ISNULL()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325(SQL.90).aspx) or [COALESCE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349(SQL.90).aspx) function, which allows you to specify an alternative value when underlying column is NULL.